# How to center a buttons text when it also has a image?

Tags: swiftui

In the following code I'm trying to produce a layout that centers the button text, while having an image on the right hand side. Currently the text is offset by the width of the image rather than being centered (I've added a `.` in a label so that you can see its not centred. I'd expect the `.` to be above the `B` in the buttons text).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(".") // Center point
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("ABC")
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that involves a technique mentioned before but accounts for long strings and variably-sized images:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var imageWidth: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(".")
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                ZStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                            .background(GeometryReader {
                                Color.clear.preference(key: ImageWidthPrefKey.self,
                                                       value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.width)
                            })
                            .onPreferenceChange(ImageWidthPrefKey.self) {
                                imageWidth = $0
                            }
                    }
                    Text("A long string that will probably wrap when it reaches the end and be a couple of lines long")
                       .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                       .padding(.horizontal,imageWidth)
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
    struct ImageWidthPrefKey : PreferenceKey {
        static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
        static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
            value = value + nextValue()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible approach is to use overlay - text is at center by default, but image can be place where needed.

*Note: of course if your text is dynamic and can be long then it is needed some more complicated solution, but expectation probably would be different*

So, for your snapshot

[image: demo]

```
Button(action: {}, label: {
      Text("ABC")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .overlay(Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill").padding(),
            alignment: .trailing)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ZStack` containing an `HStack { Spacer()`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(".") // Center point
            
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                ZStack {
                    Text("ABC")
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: ABC is centered, with Profile button on right]

Comment: I thought about this, but I figured that having both in the same HStack meant that they could never overlap - which is nice behaviour for incase the text grows. It would be awesome to center the text and keep that behaviour, I'm not sure if its possible without hugely overcomplicating things!

Comment: @user1636130 yeah that would be kind of complicated. Should the text extend all the way to the left, but still stop at the image? Or should it stop at the left as if there was another image there?

Comment: If you want to avoid overlap, I’d just stick an invisible copy of the image on the other side. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sad but simple:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(".") // Center point
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                       .opacity(0)
                       .accessibility(hidden: true)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("ABC")
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```